# Memory being corrupted after method returns

Tags: c++

I know it I am just missing something stupid but I am so frustrated I just can't see it. When I run the below code against a file with 3 fields in it "field1;field2;field3" the tasks are printed out correctly in the retrieveTasks method. When the method returns back to main the output is corrupted. I know it is stupid and I am just missing it. I have tried changing CourseName, TaskDescription, etc to arrays instead of char*. I have tried passing fileString in as a char*, I have tried with strcpy and without. Can anyone point me in a direction?

```
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 101;
const int MAX_TASK_ITEMS = 255;
const char NEWLINE = '\n';
const char DELIMETER[] = ";";
const char FILENAME[] = "tasks.txt";

struct Task {
  char* CourseName;
  char* TaskDescription;
  char* DueDate;
  char FileString[300];

  void printTask() {
    cout << CourseName << DELIMETER << TaskDescription << DELIMETER  << DueDate << endl;
  }

  void initializeFromFileString(char fileString[]) {
    strcpy(FileString, fileString);
    CourseName = strtok(FileString, DELIMETER);
    TaskDescription = strtok(NULL, DELIMETER);
    DueDate = strtok(NULL, DELIMETER);
  }
};

struct TaskList {
  Task Tasks[MAX_TASK_ITEMS];
  int TaskCount;

  void initialize() {
    TaskCount = 0;

    return;
  }

  void addTask(Task task) {
    Tasks[TaskCount] = task;
    TaskCount++;

    return;
  }

  void printTasks() {
    for(int TaskNum = 0; TaskNum < TaskCount; TaskNum++) {
      cout << TaskNum + 1 << ".      ";
      Tasks[TaskNum].printTask();
      cout << endl;
    }

    return;
  }

  // Load data from the file. Will return -1 if it fails for any reason.
  // Otherwise it returns the number of records read.
  int retrieveTasks(const char* fileName) {
    int isSuccessfulOpen = 0;
    int recordsRead = 0;
    ifstream inFile;

    isSuccessfulOpen = openFile(inFile, fileName);

    if(!isSuccessfulOpen) {
      return -1;
    }

    // Read input file and store in appropriate arrays
    while(inFile.eof() == false) {
      char fileLine[MAX_STRING_LENGTH * 3];
      Task task;

      inFile.getline(fileLine, MAX_STRING_LENGTH * 3, NEWLINE);
      inFile.ignore(UINT_MAX, NEWLINE);
      task.initializeFromFileString(fileLine);
      addTask(task);
      recordsRead++;
    }
    inFile.close();

    return recordsRead;
  }
};

int main() {
  bool isFinished = false;
  TaskList taskList;

  taskList.initialize();
  taskList.retrieveTasks(FILENAME);
  taskList.printTasks();

  return 0;
}



int openFile(ifstream& inFile, const char* fileName) {
  inFile.open(fileName);

  // Veryify that the file is valid. If not print error message.
  if(inFile.is_open() == false) {
    cout << "File " << fileName << " does not exist. Please provide a valid file path." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

// Open file for writing
int openFile(ofstream& outFile, const char* fileName) {
  outFile.open(fileName);

  // Veryify that the file is valid. If not print error message and exit.
  if(outFile.is_open() == false)
  {
    cout << "File " << fileName << " does not exist. Please provide a valid file path." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings and libraries ?

Comment: Indeed. Using C++ techniques would save you from the Rule of Three/Five problems you have going on, not to mention make the code cleaner and easier to follow.

Comment: I concur. Your local buffer makes the copy-ctor and assignment operator fairly trivial, but honestly this should be done with `std::string` objects and a standard collection class like `std::vector<>` for your task list. It would make the code *much* cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an assignment for school and the requirements are that we use cstrings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CourseName`, `TaskDescription`, `DueDate` all point to memory in the array existing in the `task` object created inside the `while` loop. Since this `task` object is local scope, they contain garbage once `retrieveTasks` has finished executing.

Changes needed

1. Your TaskCount always holds one more than the count - hence this needs to be reduced by 1.

   ```
   for(int TaskNum = 0; TaskNum < TaskCount; TaskNum++) {
   ```

   changed to

   ```
   for(int TaskNum = 0; TaskNum < TaskCount -1 ; TaskNum++) {
   ```
2. Removed Task object from the while loop.
3. `AddTask` takes a char * instead of Task. `AddTask` calls `initializeFromFileString` so that the `strcpy` is done to the string inside the Task object of the array. And `strtok` is also called on this string
4. Change

   ```
   while(inFile.eof() == false) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   while(inFile) {
   ```
5. Removed

   ```
   inFile.ignore(UINT_MAX, NEWLINE);
   ```

Fixed Code

```
struct Task {
  char* CourseName;
  char* TaskDescription;
  char* DueDate;
  char FileString[300];

  void printTask() {
    cout << CourseName << DELIMETER << TaskDescription << DELIMETER  << DueDate << endl;
  }

  void initializeFromFileString(char fileString[]) {
    strcpy(FileString, fileString);
    CourseName = strtok(FileString, DELIMETER);
    TaskDescription = strtok(NULL, DELIMETER);
    DueDate = strtok(NULL, DELIMETER);
  }

};



int openFile(ifstream& inFile, const char* fileName) {
  inFile.open(fileName);

  // Veryify that the file is valid. If not print error message.
  if(inFile.is_open() == false) {
    cout << "File " << fileName << " does not exist. Please provide a valid file path." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

// Open file for writing
int openFile(ofstream& outFile, const char* fileName) {
  outFile.open(fileName);

  // Veryify that the file is valid. If not print error message and exit.
  if(outFile.is_open() == false)
  {
    cout << "File " << fileName << " does not exist. Please provide a valid file path." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

struct TaskList {
  Task Tasks[MAX_TASK_ITEMS];
  int TaskCount;

  void initialize() {
    TaskCount = 0;

    return;
  }

  void addTask(char * t) {
    Tasks[TaskCount].initializeFromFileString(t);
    TaskCount++;

    return;
  }

  void printTasks() {
    for(int TaskNum = 0; TaskNum < TaskCount - 1; TaskNum++) {
      cout << TaskNum + 1 << ".      ";
      Tasks[TaskNum].printTask();
      cout << endl;
    }

    return;
  }

  // Load data from the file. Will return -1 if it fails for any reason.
  // Otherwise it returns the number of records read.
  int retrieveTasks(const char* fileName) {
    int isSuccessfulOpen = 0;
    int recordsRead = 0;
    ifstream inFile;

    isSuccessfulOpen = openFile(inFile, fileName);

    if(!isSuccessfulOpen) {
      return -1;
    }

    // Read input file and store in appropriate arrays
    while(inFile) {
      char fileLine[MAX_STRING_LENGTH * 3];

      inFile.getline(fileLine, MAX_STRING_LENGTH * 3, NEWLINE);

      addTask(fileLine);
        printTasks();

      recordsRead++;
    }
    inFile.close();

    return recordsRead;
  }
};
```

Quite obviously, this whole program would be much simpler and less error prone if you wrote it in `C++` instead of writing it in `C inside classes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a huge help. It would be nice if I could use C++ classes, last term we were able to, but the requirements for this term only allow cstrings. Thanks again for all your help.